# How to replace a number in a file with its sum?

Tags: c++, input, file-io, sum, fstream

I'd like to write a program that gets an integer in a file, sums it with a input number and replace the previous integer in the file with the result of the sum. I thought the following code would work, but there's a 0 written in the file that remains 0, no matter the integer I input. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream arq;
    arq.open("file.txt");
    int points, total_points;
    cin >> points;

    arq >> total_points;
    total_points += points;
    arq << total_points; 
        
}
```

Comment: Did you try closing the file, then re-opening it in write mode, exclusively?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Now I did it and it worked. Thank you. But I didn't close it, I just directly reopened it, since  I read you don't need to close if/of/fstream. Is it a buggy solution?

Comment: @Jonas That solution _may_ cause confusing results just like the one I mention at the end of my answer. It's actually very close to what I'm doing in the code example I made (except that I don't reopen the file, but rewind instead).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot, now I understand. (Also, I accepted the answers, I actually didn't know that was a thing).

Comment: @Jonas You're welcome and great! That should make some people happy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading and writing the input file separately as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream arq("file.txt");
    int points=0, total_points=0;
    cin >> points;

    arq >> total_points;
   
    total_points += points;
    arq.close();
    ofstream output("file.txt");
    
    output  << total_points;
    output.close();
    
        
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BxorUboNd).

Comment: This also works, thank you. I thought since I used fstream, which is for both reading and writing, I could do it without having to open it again... Would you know why it doesn't work like that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've opened the file for both reading and writing you need to set the output position indicator to position 0 before you write the new value to the file.

Example:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* filename = "file.txt";
    if(std::fstream arq(filename); arq) {
        if(int total_points; arq >> total_points) {
            if(int points; std::cin >> points) {
                total_points += points;
                // rewind the output position pointer to the start of the file
                arq.seekp(0);
                arq << total_points;
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::perror(filename);
    }
}
```

Note though that if you want to write a *shorter* value to the file, you may end up with a file looking like this:

Before:

```
123456
```

After writing `45` to the file:

```
453456
```

So, I recommend the approach in [Anoop Rana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259892/7582247) which truncates the file before writing to it.